# teradata sql match regular expression

Tags: teradata

My code current strips: https://www.website.com/events

but I want to strip everything up to the /events, so it would be

```
https://www.website.com
```

I feel like I am close, but I am missing something ?

This is in Teradata SQL.

```
select 'https://www.website.com/events/143403?sid=1090794&mid=35' as string_to_search
,REGEXP_SUBSTR(string_to_search, '^.*(?=(/))',1,1,'i') as extract_domain
```

Comment: Regarding the error you received when you run @DuduMarkovitz query: That's strange, works fine on my 15.10. Can you run `select * from dbc.FunctionsV
 where functionname = 'regexp_substr'` and check if there's a function in another database besides `TD_SYSFNLIB`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always got the scheme in your URLs you can use a simple

```
strtok(PAGREF_URL, '/',2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the beginning of the string `^`, take everything `.*` up to the 1st place `?` where there is

- No slash behind `(?<!/)`
- A slash in front `(?=/)`
- but not 2 slashes in front `(?!//)`

---

```
select  'https://www.website.com/events/143403?sid=1090794&mid=35'  as string_to_search
        ,regexp_substr(string_to_search, '^.*?(?<!/)(?=/)(?!//)')   as extract_domain
;
```

> https://www.website.com

Comment: can you explain (?<!/)(?=/)(?!//)   ?

Comment: Also, I get this error when I execute: Executed as Single statement.  Failed [9881 : HY000] Function 'REGEXP_SUBSTR' called with an invalid number or type of parameters 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.405 
 
STATEMENT 1: Select Statement failed.

Comment: it works on the Sample posted, but once I apply to the real data column with the URLs in the column I get the error...

Comment: The code is fine. I have no idea what you are doing there. Check if you have character set issues.

Comment: How would I check for character set issues ?  the column that I am working with is a VARCHAR(1500) that stores the different PAGE_REFERENCE_URLS   I basically want to strip the domain and do a count on those.

Comment: LATIN / UNICODE / GRAPHIC? run `show table mytable`and check

Comment: show table mytable; doesn't do anything :-) in Teradata  I get nothing back

Comment: SELECT * FROM DBC.DBCINFOV;  VERSION 15.10.03.05
LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE Standard
RELEASE 15.10.03.05

Comment: It is 5 minutes to midnight and I don't have too much patient right now. Are you a newbie to Teradata?

Comment: If "mytable" is not a table but a view then you got an error. use `show select * from mytable` instead

Comment: Yes I am new to Teradata, I hate it.  We used to be on Oracle and it was 100 times better.  Worst decision ever was to move to Teradata with Tera-problems :- )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138374/discussion-between-dudu-markovitz-and-ray-kodiak).

Comment: PAGREF_URL VARCHAR(1500) CHARACTER SET UNICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC TITLE 'PAGE_REF_URL',

Comment: @dnoeth - Hi buddy. Any idea regarding the error above?